# How to encode URL in javascript function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, php, html

1.Hey Everyone I am try to call new page when i click on Button while i have made button in HTML table where data retrieve from Database. For this i made javascript function have URL as a parameter and i pass parameter in Function call on onClick attribute but it does not work plz guide me thanks in advance

2. MY javascript code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function popUp(url) {
window.open(url,'PHP Pop Up','width=300,height=300');
}
</script>
```

```html
<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='button' onclick='popUp('http://localhost/Prac/UpdatePage.php')' name='tempId' id='".$row["ID"]."' value='Edit'/><form></td>
```

Comment: You cannot do 'popUp' use " and ' : "popUp('url')"

Comment: Have used that but got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Succesfully by removing colons
<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='button' onclick=popUp('http://localhost/Prac/UpdatePage.php') name='tempId' id='".$row["ID"]."' value='Edit'/><form></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

`<td><form action='detailform.php' method='POST'><input type='button' onclick='popUp("http://localhost/Prac/UpdatePage.php")' name='tempId' id='".$row["ID"]."' value='Edit'/><form></td>`

You cant use same quote for onclick  and for parameter.  i changed it.

Now i am using double quote for parameter

Comment: i have already tried that but it give error coz i retrieved Data from Database in this table and also i made this button in separate column dynamically according to number of records and assign record id to button id